# Error displaying ng-bootstrap modal: Unrecognized feature: ' '

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have an error displaying ng-bootstrap modal, which says this:
[image]

Unfortunately, I don't event know where to look for the solution. I assume this kind of error might be caused by ngb version or smth. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you trying to open the modal from component ts file OnInit?

Comment: @kobe No, I don't use OnInit to open the modal.

Comment: do you use YouTube embed?

Comment: I use iframe into ng-template to display youtube video.